# powershell pass array to another function

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a function that gets all the processes accessing a particular folder and split it's process id. In this function, all the ids are saved in an array. I want to give this array to another function. The code i have is:

```
$CLRJson = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\Users\Lokal-keeran\Documents\Ausbildung\Aufgaben\Powershell\PI-Kill\PIKill.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    ##Directory path to be scanned to see if there are processes accessing the files in the given directory.
    $CLRDIRProd = $CLRJson.CLRExtproc_PARA_PROD.CLRDIR 
    $PIDGF = @()
    
    #Get all Processes, accessing a folder
    function Get-FileHandle ($HPath){
        $handle = handle.exe $HPath
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Process = $handle | Select-String -Pattern '.*?(?= +type:)' | Select-String -Pattern 'mstsc.exe' -NotMatch
        Foreach ($pro in $Process.Matches.Value) {
            $AddtoArray = $pro -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1
            $PIDGF += $AddtoArray
        }
    }
    
    #Stop the Processes accessing that folder
    function stop-FileHandle ([string[]]$HPathtoGFH) {
        Get-FileHandle -HPath $CLRDIRProd
        "The Third Value of this Array is: $PIDGF[2]"
        #Stop Command......
    }
stop-FileHandle -HPathtoGFH $CLRDIRProd
```

If i revoke stop-filehandle no output will be shown. Also the global array doesn't contain any value. But if i run the commands in the function Get-Filehandle, it shows me some process ids  one below the another, just like it should be.....

Why array could not be given to another function ?

Comment: @vonPryz I forgot to copy the array difinition. In the Get-FilHandle funtion, i am adding every foreach value to the array $PIDGF. This array should be accessible for all funtion in the script. The function Stop-Filehandle calls the Get-Filehandle function. After that i am trying to display the 3rd proccess id in the array. but that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Inside function `Get-FileHandle`, stuff is added to a function **local** variable called `$PIDGF`.
Since you have declared your array **outside** the function, you should use `script-scoping` inside the function:

```
$script:PIDGF += $AddtoArray
```

Then in the `stop-FileHandle` function you need to use a subexpression (`$()`)around the value you want to output:

```
"The Third Value of this Array is: $($script:PIDGF[2])"
```

Much better would be if the `Get-FileHandle` simply **outputs** the array so the calling function can capture that in a variable:

```
function Get-FileHandle ($HPath){
    $handle = handle.exe $HPath
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Process = $handle | 
        Select-String -Pattern '.*?(?= +type:)' | 
        Select-String -Pattern 'mstsc.exe' -NotMatch
    foreach ($pro in $Process.Matches.Value) {
        # just output the values, so the calling function receives an array
        $pro -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1
    }
}

#Stop the Processes accessing that folder
function Stop-FileHandle ([string[]]$HPathtoGFH) {
    $PIDGF = Get-FileHandle -HPath $CLRDIRProd
    "The Third Value of this Array is: $($PIDGF[2])"
    #Stop Command......
}

Stop-FileHandle -HPathtoGFH $CLRDIRProd
```

This way you do not use `+=` concatenation to an existing array which is both time and memory consuming, plus you do not have to worry about scoping.